# What is the name of this type of bell?

Tags: instruments, fl-studio, instrumentation

I'm looking for some keywords I can search for samples similar to the bells in the background of link 1, and also 1:03 of link 2. I bought FLStudio Producer Edition which comes with Sytrus, but none of the ~12 Sytrus Bell presets sound even close to the "doom" style bells in the links. I feel like I'm missing some qualifier or adjective on "bell" to get that specific type of bell, but I don't know what it is.

I've tried "deep bells", "church bells", and "doom bells", but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Any tips?

Comment: How about using any bell sound and changing it in a tool like Audacity until it sounds what you like?

Comment: I don't know the properties of sound well enough to do that, but I figured out today the qualifier I was looking for: "tubular bells"

Comment: Hello RPGillespie - here we don't answer identification questions as it's unlikely to be helpful to future readers. I'm sure someone would be happy to help if you could re-write your question in a more general way. See the music FAQ for more details.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the fact that it's layered with bass and chords that makes it sound so big and doomy?

Comment: @naught101 No, I was specifically trying to identify what I now know are called tubular bells or orchestral chimes

Comment: @jjmusicnotes Sorry, based on the tag descriptions I thought it was appropriate. At any rate, you can close the question if it makes you feel better; I've resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

This bell sound is made by tubular bells, also known as concert or orchestral chimes.